# How to stop webbrowser control refreshing when server requests it

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser control that points at a webpage that holds some fields that change quickly. When these fields change the server seems to request that the webpage refreshes. This poses a problem if programatically interact with the webbroswer. Is there anyway to force the webbrowser to not refresh? No real code to show. since I'm hoping this is a one line property I can create/add.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the WebBrowser.Stop() Method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.stop%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

Comment: Hi. I've tried this and it doesn't stop the webpage reloading the data. Any other ideas?